# How do I run PHP code only once in a Wordpress loop?

Tags: php, wordpress, bbpress

I'm trying to run some PHP code once in a loop in bbpress (wordpress forums)

The code I'm trying to run is a sidebar:

```
<?php if ( function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') && dynamic_sidebar(5) ) : else : ?>
    <p class="empty-content-area">
        <span>Oops! No sweet stuff in here</span><br />
        <a href="wp-admin/widgets.php">Add a widget</a>
    </p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I would like this to display only once below the first reply and nothing else after the 2nd, 3rd reply etc.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this kind of quick-and-dirty thing:

```
<? if ($c++ == 0 && function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') && dynamic_sidebar(5) ) { ?>
    <p class="empty-content-area">
        <span>Oops! No sweet stuff in here</span><br />
        <a href="wp-admin/widgets.php">Add a widget</a>
    </p>
<? } ?>
```

Comment: this might sound stupid but i added the following 
<?php if($c++ == 0) {
function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') && dynamic_sidebar(5); 
  } 
  ?>
with no luck its still displaying after each reply

Comment: Yes, because your `if` had no effect. Check my edited answer.

Comment: What's the $c++ bit supposed to do?  $c is undefined in your snippet

Comment: Undefined variables are set to 0. This is PHP's magic. First time, `$c` is 0. But `$c++` means it will be incremented next time you use it, so it will be 1, and the condition will not be verified.

Comment: im not sure if im allowed to post link here but the above still not working it must be something im doing [link](http://www.diablo247.com/topic/just-got-my-barb-to-lvl-60/)

Comment: i used `<? if ($c++ == 0 && function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') && dynamic_sidebar(5) ); ?>` and worked like a charm when i placed it in the right place lol im such a noob